# Задержка при нажатии кнопки на форме (Xamarin.Android)

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

Пишу приложение для Android на Xamarin (не Xamarin.Forms). Создал кнопку в MainActivity, которая открывает другую страницу. При нажатии происходит задержке в полсекунды, во время которой я могу успеть нажать кнопку еще раз. В итоге страница откроется два раза. Пробовал тоже самое на Xamarin.Forms, на нем задержка вообще почти в две секунды. Задержка воспроизводится как на эмуляторе, так и на реальном телефоне. На открываемой странице размещено только текстовое поле.

Можно ли убрать\уменьшить эту задержку? Если нет, то есть какое-нибудь штатное средство или настройка, чтобы нельзя было открыть две страницы при нажатии одной кнопки (т.е. блокировка повторного нажатия, пока страница не открылась)?

Код по событию нажатия кнопки:

```
var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(SettingsActivity));
StartActivity(intent);
```